# Почему не компилируется less-файл в webpack

Tags: webpack

Посмотрел документацию по extract-text-webpack-plugin, но никак не могу запустить его. Просто игнорирует style.less > style.css

```
var StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin = require('static-site-generator-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
var data = require('./data')

module.exports = {
  entry: './entry.js',

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname,
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/, query: {
          presets: ['es2016', 'react']
        }
       },
        { test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader")},
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")},
        { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
        { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
      new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin('bundle.js', data.routes, data)
  ]

}
```

Comment: Теперь всё работает и готовый общий css кладёт в папку dist.
https://github.com/prospik/webpack-react-less/blob/master/webpack.config.js